# How to cache images in intent service (background thread) using Universal Image Loader

Tags: android, caching, universal-image-loader

I am testing upgrading to use Android Universal Image Loader 1.9.0.  I have tested this on Android 4.2.  I've come across a problem where I am downloading and caching images in an intent service to be run on a background thread to not interfere with the user.  However, UIL is complaining that I am not loading these images on the main thread.  I don't want to load these images on the main thread, I just want to be able to cache them on disc in the background so that they don't need to be downloaded when the user actually views the specified images.  Is there another way to pre-cache the images on a background thread besides ImageLoader.loadImage?  If not, how do I allow pre-caching on disc on a thread that isn't the main thread?  All of this code is being run in an IntentService.

ImageLoaderConfiguration:

```
ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(
            getApplicationContext())
            .threadPriority(Thread.MAX_PRIORITY)
            .memoryCacheSize(memoryCacheSize)
            .denyCacheImageMultipleSizesInMemory()
            .threadPoolSize(5)
            .discCacheFileNameGenerator(new MyFileNameGenerator())
            .tasksProcessingOrder(QueueProcessingType.LIFO)
            .build();
```

DisplayImageOptions:

```
 DisplayImageOptions options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder().cacheOnDisc()
                .imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.NONE).build();
```

Load image code:

```
imageLoader.loadImage(imageURI, options,
            new SimpleImageLoadingListener() {
                @Override
                public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view,
                        Bitmap loadedImage)
                {
                    loadNext();  // gives a notification update and loads next image URI in queue
                }

                @Override
                public void onLoadingFailed(String imageUri, View view,
                        FailReason failReason)
                {
                    loadNext(); // gives a notification update and loads next image URI in queue
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually UIL doesn't provide methods for preloading images, i.e. just to add to disc cache. It always returns decoded Bitmap.

But in your case you can use `loadImageSync(...)`. I think it's more appropriate for you.

Comment: Looks like this bypasses the handler check on the main thread as well.  Thanks.

Comment: I am trying to achieve exact same thing @user1236327 but i do not see loadImageSync caches, how did you manage in your case ?

Comment: Did you enable caching in options which you pass in `loadImageSync(...)`?

Comment: I didn't change options while calling loadImageSync i used only imageUrl method, and on default option i have cacheOnDisc(true) but still it skips caching...

Comment: Strange... Using loadImageSync(String uri, DisplayImageOptions options) method instead of loadImageSync(String uri) solved caching problem. I didn't think it would affect, because in your library you receive default option if option parameter is null, but somehow it does...

Comment: Did you set default options in config before?

Answer (score 0):

After diving into UIL's code, I figured out a solution.  Not sure it is the best one but may help someone out in the future.  If you set your own handler in the DisplayImageOptions, it skips the check to make sure the handler is on the main thread:

```
DisplayImageOptions options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder().cacheOnDisc()
            .imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.NONE)
            .handler(new Handler()) // added this line
            .build();
```